# access a element within hidden div element using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having an iframe inside a div element which is hidden/display none, I want to get the href attribute of a  tag using javascript my code is

HTML

```
<div id="questions" style="display: none;">
    <iframe id="article_frame" width="100%" height="100%">
        <a href="someurl" id="en_link">Click here</a>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

JS

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert("Hello " + window.document.getElementById("article_frame"));
}
```

But I am getting alert as "Hello null" any solution

Thanks

Comment: The code in your post is only a pesudo-code, and you've the anchor in a real file loaded to the `iframe`?

Comment: You want to display a list of `href` link inside an `iframe`?

Comment: Please answer the question! At first, your HTML is invalid, secondly, `#article_frame` is the `iframe` you have, it shouldn't be `null`...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks All,

I have got the answer with javascript it just simple code

```
var anchor = document.getElementById('en_article_link').firstChild;
var newLink = anchor.getAttribute("href")+"sid="+sidvalue;
anchor.setAttribute("href", newLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i feel this may be a slight overkill but it will get you what you require (the href value of the anchor tag inside the iframe) :

```
window.onload = function() {

        var frame = window.document.getElementById("article_frame");

        var myString = frame.childNodes[0].textContent
          , parser = new DOMParser()
          , doc = parser.parseFromString(myString, "text/xml");

        var hrefValue = doc.firstChild.getAttribute('href');

        alert("Hello " + hrefValue);
}
```

I guess it depends on your requirements but another way would be to create a string  and then using functions: substring and indexof you could get your value. Here is how you would get the string:

```
window.onload = function() {

        var frame = window.document.getElementById("article_frame");

        var elementString = frame.childNodes[0].textContent;
        //then perform your functions on the string here
}
```

Comment: NOTE: with the second option, the string includes escape sequences: '\n'

Answer (score -1):

Note that you can only access the contents of an iframe that contains a page on the same domain due to the [Same-Origin Policy (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

I recommend using jQuery for this.  The tricks here are:

1. Wait for the iframe to finish loading `$("#article_frame").ready()`
2. Access the iframe's document `$("#article_frame").contents()`

From there you're just handling the task at hand:

```
$("#article_frame").ready(function() {
  alert("Hello " + $("#article_frame").contents().find("#en_link").href);
});
```